# How can i search and replace multiple strings in a line - Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I want to search and replace multiple strings in a line(string).

consider I have three variables

```
my $fruitone = "apple";
my $fruittwo = "orange";
my $fruitthree = "banana";

my string1 = "I have one ${fruitone} two ${fruittwo} and three ${fruitthree}";
```

I want to replace `$fruitone` with `apple` and so on.

My end result should look like

```
I have one apple two orange and three banana.
```

I am able to replace one by `string1 =~ /$\{(\w+)\}/$$1/;`

But I need help on accessing `$2` and `$3` items

Comment: `my string` is a syntax error (missing $). Also, double quotes interpolate variables.

Comment: I believe I didn't understand the question. :-( What's the purpose of "manually" interpolating variables in a string when Perl will do it automatically? `"I have one ${fruitone} …"` yields `"I have one apple …"` anyway (when using `"`), doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression only has one capture group, so there is no `$2` or `$3` to access.

If you want to match multiple things you need to add the g option to the end though, like this

```
$string1=~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$$1/g;
```

Note: This is really not a good way to code this though as it allows any variable to substituted into the string. You should consider using a hash to store the values to limit what can be replaced.

```
my %fruit=("fruitone" => "apple", "fruittwo"=>"orange","fruitthree" => "banana");
my $string1= 'I have one ${fruitone} two ${fruittwo} and three ${fruitthree}';

$string1 =~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$fruit{$1}/g;
```

Comment: Yes thank you I am using hash to do that, For simplicity I wrote it like this, your answer helped thanks!

Comment: @vijay In future you should ask the question you want the answer to in the first place using actual code, rather than a similar question that happens to result in an answer you can use.

Comment: @Chris: Your answer is a poor one and you are in no position to chastise the OP. Have you tested your code?

Comment: @Borodin it worked but I didn't test it with the OP's regex which I see now has more typos in it :/

Comment: @Chris: It is *your* regex once you have posted it as an answer. Please stop blaming others for your mistakes.

Comment: I think your code should be: `$string1 =~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$$1/ge;` with an `e` at the end to evaluate. However, it still wouldn't work with lexically scoped variables (`my` variables), the should be `our` variables instead.

Comment: @KjetilS. that is what I initially thought too, but having experimented it doesn't seem to need the `e` for

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
my($fruitone, $fruittwo, $fruitthree) = ("apple", "orange", "banana");
my $string= 'I have one ${fruitone} two ${fruittwo} and three ${fruitthree}';
$string =~ s/(\$\{\w+\})/eval$1/ge;
```

Or this:

```
our($fruitone, $fruittwo, $fruitthree) = ("apple", "orange", "banana");
my $string= 'I have one ${fruitone} two ${fruittwo} and three ${fruitthree}';
$string =~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$$1/ge;
```

However, I recommend using a hash for your fruits if you can.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the
[`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) module,
but I cannot test with non-core modules at present as I am working with an Android tablet

I think this should work

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';

my $fruitone   = "apple";
my $fruittwo   = "orange";
my $fruitthree = "banana";

my $string = 'I have one ${fruitone} two ${fruittwo} and three ${fruitthree}';

print interpolate($string);
```